# Setting up Kafka on AWS with separate Schema Registry and Kafka Connect Docker images

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

We are trying to set up Kafka on AWS. We are planning to use MSK offered by AWS for our Kafka. Howerver, we need to install Schema Registry and Kafka Connect separately. We are considering installing these in docker containers. So my questions are:

1. Does anyone know what are the most suitable images to use (lightweight) only for schema registry and Connect?
2. As far as I understand we should install Connect on a cluster. Does this apply even to schema registry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing Confluent Docker images for both the registry and conncet should work fine.

Deploying only one Registry would become a single point of failure, so yes, deploy more than one and use a load-balancer on them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! We tried with those ones, but we havent managed to get them working yet. The documentation is  a bit of a jungle...